# How to solve this differential equation with the initial condition?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> How to solve this differential equation with the initial condition
> $$\begin{cases} x(0)=1\\ x'(t) \cos t - 2x \sin t = 1 \end{cases}$$ for $t \in (\frac{-\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$?

I tried to use $z(t)=x(t)\cos(t), z'(t)=x'(t)\cos(t) -x(t) \sin(t)$, but then I have $z(t)-x(t)\sin t =1$, so there is still a problem to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $x' - (2\tan t)x = \sec t$. Can you take it from here as you have a linear $1$st order DE.